# Field oriented control motor controller: is the measured Iq rms or the peak current?

Tags: motor, three-phase

Say the regulator regulates Iq to be 1A, is the actual motor current 1A RMS or 1A/sqrt(2)=0.707A?

Comment: What type of motor is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really comes down to the controller being used and how they expose the "setting" to the user.

Square root is actually annoyingly hard for microcontrollers/FPGA's to implement (no convenient approximations like sin,cos,tan re.CORDIC) but it is relatively trivial todo a final multiplication by 0.707 if end-results or settings are to be exposed as RMS quantities

The equations associated with park-clark transformation resolve around peak

$$
I_\alpha = I_a 
$$
$$
I_\beta = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}I_a + \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}I_b
$$
Assuming a,b,c are balanced & of equal amplitude and thus such a reduction is valid

$$
I_q  = I_\alpha sin(\theta) + I_\beta cos(\theta)
$$
Where \$\theta\$ is the present \$\omega\$t

THUS at the centre of a DQ (or a FOC) controller Iq will be a peak quantity